# Send "Custom Attribute" when sending Email via TriggeredSend

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap, c#, website-integration

I'm very new to the Exact Target SOAP API. I was wondering if someone could tell me how to send an attribute that isn't part of the subscriber object, via a Triggered Send. I've managed to successfully send the FirstName, FullName, EmailAddress etc. objects and they come through in an email. However, I have an attribute/field called "Count" which doesn't belong to the Subscriber and thus comes through as %%Count%%. The following code is what I'm using to send emails thus far (its rough, I'm mid spike).

```
 var binding = new BasicHttpBinding
        {
            Name = "UserNameSoapBinding",
            Security =
            {
                Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential,
                Message = {ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName}
            },
            ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0),
            OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0),
            CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0),
            SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)
        };

        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx");

        var etFramework = new SoapClient(binding, endpoint);

        etFramework.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
        etFramework.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "test123!";



        var tsd = new TriggeredSendDefinition();
        tsd.CustomerKey = "TSD_RegisteredUsers";



        var ts = new TriggeredSend();
        ts.TriggeredSendDefinition = tsd;


        ts.Subscribers = new Subscriber[1];

        ts.Subscribers[0] = new Subscriber();
        ts.Subscribers[0].EmailAddress = "test@test.com";
        ts.Subscribers[0].SubscriberKey = "test@test.com";
        ts.Subscribers[0].Attributes = new Attribute[2];
        ts.Subscribers[0].Attributes[0] = new Attribute {Name = "firstname", Value = "Test"};
        ts.Subscribers[0].Attributes[1] = new Attribute { Name = "Count", Value = "1005" };

        string requestID;
        string status;

        var results = etFramework.Create(new CreateOptions(), new APIObject[] { ts }, out requestID, out status);

        //Output the Overall Status of the Request
        Console.WriteLine("Request Results: " + status);

        //Output the Status of the Triggered Send Call
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Triggered Send Status Code: " + result.StatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine("Triggered Send Status Message: " + result.StatusMessage);
        }



        Console.ReadLine();
```

I've read up on Data Extensions but I'm not 100% sure how to use them in a Triggered Send Scenario and they seem over kill for a single number in an email. I've also read the article on Scenarios for triggered sends (http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/triggered_email_scenario_guide_for_developers/) but that doesn't really shed any light onto it. I'd really appreciate a step by step breakdown.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure it matters but the number for the count going into the email is dynamic and generated on the website side. It changes quite often so I'm not sure how suitable it is for storing in the ET UI